# Idiomatic Java "finally" block that only runs on exception

Tags: java

If you have some cleanup code that needs to run regardless of whether an exception was thrown, `try { ... } finally { ... }` is what you need.  But what if you want that cleanup code to only run in the event of an exception?

One possible solution is this:

```
boolean ok = false;
try {
    doWork();
    ok = true;
} finally {
    if (!ok) {
        doCleanup();
    }
}
```

It does exactly what I want, but I wondered if there was a more natural way to express the idea.

This alternative doesn’t pass muster:

```
try {
    doWork();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    doCleanup();
    throw e; // BAD: Cant do this unless the enclosing function is declared to throw Throwable
}
```

I suppose I could catch Exception instead of Throwable, but I don't like the idea that a non-Exception throwable will bypass the cleanup code.  After all, a regular `finally` block still runs even for non-Exception throwables.

Aside: In C++, you would simply use a *catch-all* block:

```
try {
    doWork();
} catch (...) {
    doCleanup();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: You first alternative should work fine. You don't need to declare that you are throwing `Throwable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Java 7 this is legal code:

```
public static void method() {
  try {
    // stuff which doesn't declare checked exceptions
  } catch (Throwable t) { 
    throw t; 
  }
}
```

The improved language rules allow this because static analysis can prove that `t` will not actually be any checked exception.

Likewise, you are only required to declare the minimum necessary checked exceptions:

```
public static void method() throws IOException {
  try {
    throwingMethod();
  } catch (Throwable t) { throw t; }
}

static void throwingMethod() throws IOException {}
```

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Also it does seem to compile in Java 7.

Comment: Since it works in Java 7 and that’s what I’m targeting (sorry, I should have specified in the OP), this one the check mark.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `try`...`finally` block, then one of two cases applies:

1. You have a `throws` clause on the method, and the `try` block may throw a checked exception.

Have a `catch` block that catches `RuntimeException`s and any checked exceptions:

```
catch (RuntimeException | YourCheckedException e) {
    // Cleanup
    throw e;
}
```

2. You don't have a `throws` clause, and the `try` block may only throw an unchecked exception.

Catch `RuntimeException`, which doesn't need to be declared in `throws`.

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // Cleanup
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: What about `Error`s? I think OP wants cleanup in those cases as well.

Comment: I suppose I could add Error to the multi-catch, but that still wouldn't cover any diabolical Throwable that was neither an Error nor an Exception.

Comment: @Will Only Exception and Error extend Throwable and Throwable should never be directly extended. If there exists a Throwable that is neither an Exception nor an Error then somebody's done something they shouldn't have.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik An `Error` signifies that something so bad has happened, it shouldn't even need to be caught.  But if you insist, you can add `Error` to the list of throwable types to be caught, e.g. `catch (IOException | RuntimeException | Error e)`.

Comment: Good point, Radiodef! Of course, nothing’s stopping someone from directly extending Throwable, but if they did that, then the resulting subclass would be a checked exception, so they wouldn’t be able to throw it out of `doWork()` without declaring it.

Comment: @rgettman It is not true that it shouldn't be caught---that is in fact routinely done all around the industry-standard code, in exception barriers.

Answer (score 1):

> It does exactly what I want, but I wondered if there was a more natural way to express the idea.

Languages have idiomatic constructs unique to the syntax to stuff. In Java, the first option you showed:

```
boolean ok = false;
try {
    doWork();
    ok = true;
} finally {
    if (!ok) {
        doCleanup();
    }
}
```

**it is** the *idiomatic* way of doing it in Java that feels *natural* to the (no pun intended) *natural* syntax of said language.

You are looking for a natural on-error only mechanism, and Java does not have one. You are trying create a clean-up mechanism without involving compiler checks on checked throwables. One would think to use generics, but generics have restrictions (namely, one cannot parameterize a subclas of throwable.)

However, IIRC, there are ways to circumvent compiler checking by parameterizing the enclosing method with a Class, then manufacture the instance via reflection and throwing it. But, in the general case, now we are getting into the realm of the hairy for no apparent and useful reason.

I would stick to the example you showed. It is clear what it does, it is clean and there are no asinine and unexpected gotchas in it.

.ps.

For the love of God, I hope you are not using C++ catch-all idiom (at least not without preceding it with with a battery of type-specific catch blocks, including std::exception).

There is nothing worse than having to deal with code that reaches such a catch-all block. There is no freaking information whatsoever, near impossible to trace what threw it.

Been there and don't that for a living. The stuff of nightmares.